# React using 3d surface plot

Tags: reactjs, charts, 3d

in javascript i used vis.js from http://visjs.org/graph3d_examples.html 
but from react-vis the 3Dgraph component is missing.

If i am importing vis.js from a CDN server in my react app have this error:
"define is not defined no-def"

Is there another react library then react-plotly that can plot 3D surface like vis.js, or someone can help me import this vis.js to react?

Comment: Please share how you import react-vis and the code relevant to the error message.

Comment: react-vis works ok, just it doesnt have the graph3d component. I was trying to load the javascript vis library that uses AMD, that i have later learn that i cannot import on react app!

Comment: What's wrong with `react-plotly.js`?